# algorithm to check tree malfunctioning

Tags: c++

i wrote this code to check how many nodes has only left son

```
template <class T>
int Tree<T>::onlyLeftSon(Node<T> * current) //check how many left son there are on trehh
{
    if (current == NULL) //empty tree or we finish the tree
        return 0;

    return ( onlyLeftSon(current->left) + onlyLeftSon(current->right) ); // return the sum from left and right

    if (!current->left && !current->right) //if this node not have sons
        return 0;

    if (current->left && !current->right) //if this node not has only left son
        return 1;


}
```

this return 0
why?

Comment: Could you show a sample input to that function?

Comment: You have an unconditional `return` before some other code. That other code will *never* be executed. Other than that, I'm afraid it's not possible to understand the problem without something more complete.

Comment: Please use the C++11 standard "nullptr" instead of NULL.

Comment: Can I request that you avoid gender-specific replacements for words that are commonly used in this field?  It took me a moment to figure out what you meant by "son".  We refer to "children" when we talk about trees.

Comment: Ami Tavory
why?
i thought that when he finih down to the leaves and come to NULL the algorithem down to the next 2 condition and start up with the +1 or 0
why not?

Answer (score 1):

The unconditional statement:

```
    return ( onlyLeftSon(current->left) + onlyLeftSon(current->right) );
```

Always happens after the `current == NULL` check fails. This means that you will always calculate `onlyLeftSon` as the sum of the two child nodes in *all* cases, except for the `current == NULL` case where you return `0`. `0 + 0` will always be zero.

What you likely want is:

```
template <class T>
int Tree<T>::onlyLeftSon(Node<T> * current)
{
    if (current == NULL) //empty tree or we finish the tree
        return 0;

    if (!current->left && !current->right) //if this node not have sons
        return 0;

    if (current->left && !current->right) //if this node not has only left son
        return 1;

    return ( onlyLeftSon(current->left) + onlyLeftSon(current->right) );
}
```

---

At that point, the algorithm seems to be calculating **the number of leafs in a tree whose parent only has a left-leaf**. This is different from counting the number of left leafs, or left-child nodes in general:

```
    a
  /   \
 b     c
```

The tree above will return `onlyLeftSon(tree) == 0`. Why?

- When `current == a`, we have:

  - `current != NULL`, `current->left != NULL`, and `current->right != NULL`.
  - Therefore, non of the `if` statements succeed and we recurse to `b` and `c`.
  - Both `b` and `c` return `0`, because they are both childless.

Is that what you are trying to do? Or are you trying to calculate every left leaf in general?

Comment: hi
the examples did you gave is after you change my code?
and i still not get why because you take the return line to down it change and work
i thought that when he finih down to the leaves and come to NULL the algorithem down to the next 2 condition and start up with the +1 or 0
why not?

Comment: if i do 
template <class T>
int Tree<T>::onlyLeftSon(Node<T> * current)
{
    if (current == NULL) //empty tree or we finish the tree
        return 0;

    if (!current->left && !current->right) //if this node not have sons
        return 0;

    if (current->left && !current->right) //if this node not has only left son
        return 1;

    return ( onlyLeftSon(current->left) + onlyLeftSon(current->right) );
after the first not he back 1 andfinish